# Rich text in gtk-sharp?

Tags: c#, linux, mono, richtextbox, gtk#

Does anybody out there know if there is a richtextbox equivalent in gtk# or any way to replicate the functionality?

I might not need full rtf support, I could probably get by with being able to show multicolored text if a full rtf solution can't be done.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TextView widget has support for rich text (though not RTF, AFAIK). You can define styles in TextTag objects in the TextTagList of the TextBuffer that the view is showing, and apply them to ranges of text in the TextBuffer.

Comment: This property of TextBuffer seems to be called TagTable now (gtk# 2.12)